# I can't connect to SQL Server database with C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I was trying to create registration form but when I run my project am getting this error message

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Registration{
private void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHAB 
     SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=Phonebook;Integrated Security=True"); 

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[registration]([username[fullname],[Password]) VALUES('" + username.Text+"', '"+fullname.Text+"', '"+password.Text+"')");

     con.Open(); 
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     con.Close(); 
     MessageBox.Show("Congradulation You have been Registered");
}
```

The error appears on the line `con.open();`.

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes

Comment: something is wrong between the username and the fullname part
"INSERT INTO [dbo].[registration]([username[fullname],[Password])

Comment: is your machine called "Shab sqlexpress"? Id doubt it, cant have machine names with spaces.. is Shab the name of the machine? in which case shab/sqlexpress or if not, maybe ./sqlexpress .. either way its telling you it couldnt find it via named pipes

Comment: Hello, my machine name is shab, Database  server name is   SHAB\SQLEXPRESS   but when I write SHAB\SQLEXPRESS I get an error on the "\" Backslash sign

Comment: @ProfessorShab: you need to use `SHAB\\SQLEXPRESS` (**two** backslashes)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma  between `[username]` and `[fullname]`. Try like:

```
INSERT INTO ... ([username], [fullname], ...
```

Also it is very important to use sql Parameters

Answer (score 0):

First Check SQL Server Service is running.
after that check Data Source value in your Connection String, if you are using SQLExpress then it may be 
`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHAB\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=Phonebook;Integrated Security=True");`

Comment: I have added the slash as you said am getting this message
The exception is thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Login failed for user 'SHAB\Professor Shab'.
code
    
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHAB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Phonebook;User ID=SHAB\\Professor Shab;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[registration]([username],[fullname],[Password]) 
            //VALUES('" + username.Text+"', '"+fullname.Text+"', '"+password.Text+"')");
            con.Open();

Comment: if you put User id then you have to put password as well.

Answer (score 0):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

As the error indicates, your connection unable to reach SQL Server, make sure you are able to do `telnet SHAB 1433`

**If `Telnet`  fails:**

- Make sure **TCP/IP** protocol enabled, you can verify it via SQL Server Configuration manager (following screenshot for reference)
- Verify the custom port NOT Configured (via SQL Server Configuration manager) for SQL Express service

**If the custom port NOT configured**

1. Make sure **SQL Browser service is running**
2. Create a rule in Windows Firewall to accept incoming connections on TCP ports `1433` and `1434 (TCP and UDP)` - This must be done at the server where SQL Service is running
3. Restart SQL Browser service
4. Your connection should work here with `DataSource=SHAB\\SQLEXPRESS`. You can do `telnet SHAB 1433` to verify

**If the custom port configured**

1. Create a rule in Windows Firewall to accept incoming connections on Custom TCP ports - This must be done at the server where SQL Service is running
2. Restart SQL Service
3. Your connection should work here when you use `DataSource = SHAB,<custom port>`. However, you can do `telnet SHAB <custom port>` to verify

---

**SQL Server Configuration manager:**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your connection string must be in app.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
    Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
<connectionStrings>
```

import configuration from

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Add DB Connection

```
public string DbCon = 
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ToString();

var Query=@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[registration]([username[fullname],[Password]) VALUES('" + username.Text+"', '"+fullname.Text+"', '"+password.Text+"')"
using (con = new SqlConnection(DbCon))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why does the connection string need to be in app.config? The [SqlConnection constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) just takes a string parameter for connection string.

Comment: For better approach it should be in app.config otherwise you can add connection string anywhere in the project it's totally up to you

Comment: That doesn't have any bearing on the issue posted in the question though, that's just semantics of where the connection string is stored - moving the connection string to app.config won't solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you just have omitted the username and the password in your connection string.
Try the following code.

```
Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;User ID=YourUsername;Password=YourPassword
```

Comment: The connection string the OP posted uses integrated security.

Comment: This probably should be a comment!

Comment: Thank you, am new in Stack overflow thank you for assistance, private void this is the code i have written versas result

Comment: private void Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHAB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Phonebook;User ID=SHAB\\Professor Shab;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[registration]([username],[fullname],[Password]) 
            //VALUES('" + username.Text+"', '"+fullname.Text+"', '"+password.Text+"')");
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Congradulation You have been Registered");
        }

Comment: This is the error am getting 

Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Login failed for user 'SHAB\Professor Shab'.

Comment: This is the error am getting 

Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Login failed for user 'SHAB\Professor Shab'.