# "C:\USERS\ME\DATABASE.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'me-PC\me'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Basically every time I run my game MS SQL database crashes and returns this error message.

> Cannot open database "C:\USERS\ME\SOURCE\REPOS\A GIRL CALLED LORRY\A GIRL CALLED LORRY\DATABASE.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'me-PC\me'.

I did not change any of the SQL or C# code in my project to cause this error. All I did was simply modify a table within my database by adding a new column of type string.

I've tried using SMSS to open my `DataBase.mdf` file within my project to see if my user has privileges to access it, however I was unable to open my `DataBase.mdf` file because it wouldn't even show up within SMSS. So I'm not sure how I can get privileges to access my database again. I also tried removing all the changes I've added to the DB which caused the error in the first place however the error still persists.

As I've said, the error was caused by modifying a table within my database, but there is a small piece of code where the game crashes as soon as I attempt to open the database to remove data:

```
//this method is used to initialize the database.
public static void createSave() {

        //database stuff:
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\me\\source\\repos\\A Girl Called Lorry\\A Girl Called Lorry\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter();

        ds = new DataSet();
        Console.WriteLine("we are in!");
        //the below code only initializes if isNewGame is set to true.
        removeAllFromInventory();
        rewriteCurrentObjects();
        loadDefaultNpcs();
    }

//removeAllFromInventory is where it crashes.
//removes all items from inventory:
    public static void removeAllFromInventory() { //this only applies if  
//isNewGame is set to true since we want to wipe the inventory in a new game
        if (!isNewGame) return;
        con.Open(); //here is where it crashes.
        adp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM curInventoryItems", con);
        adp.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How did you add new column to the database table?

Comment: SMSS requires the database to be attached.  You can attach the database to SMSS to query the database.  You have a local database that was create with VS.  You connection string is using Integrated Security=True which indicates the database is using the current user credentials to access the database.  My first guess is you cannot access the mdf file in the connections string.  So I would check with a windows explorer that the file exists and you have access to the file.  The error indicates the user is 'me-PC\me'.  I suspect when you wrote the file the permissions of the file changed.

Comment: I can't attach my database because it doesn't show up in SMSS. the full location for my database is in C:\Users\me\source\repos\A Girl Called Lorry\A Girl Called Lorry when I try to navigate into "me" from SMSS I see nothing in the containing folders; it's just blank. Could setting Security=False work? Here's a link to an image of the DataBase.mdf in my project folder: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13uliYP2El9vkYIA6_HrZH5d28XVmjKz2/view?usp=sharing where the DataBase.mdf does exist.

Comment: Here is a link to what I see when trying to attach in SMSS: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12xU1JkXLQ7Le-QvVFUOj6DUuYi7EOIM2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So I added a new column in my table called "curInventoryObjects" which stores a list of all objects I have in my inventory in the game. Here's what the table looks like: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[curInventoryItems] (
    [Id]           INT           NOT NULL,
    [fileName]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [imageXoffset] INT           NOT NULL,
    [imageYoffset] INT           NOT NULL,
    [imageWidth]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [imageHeight]  INT           NOT NULL,
    [count]        INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Comment: I added a new column before count called "name" which was of type NVARCHAR (50) which I wanted to make so I could store unique names for each list item. That's what caused the crash in the first place because it was in the position where count was originally stored hence a crashed occured when my scripts tried to read an count when it was actually reading "name" which was a string and not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

> However I was unable to open my DataBase.mdf file because it wouldn't even show up within SMSS. So I'm not sure how I can get privileges to access my database again. I also tried removing all the changes I've added to the DB which caused the error in the first place however the error still persists.

There is confusing part in your question, when you unable to connect `.MDF` how could you remove changes that was added into DB.

However, following steps might be helpful to get your database back to normal:

1. Verify the account (`me-PC\me`) has permissions on `C:\USERS\ME\SOURCE\REPOS\A GIRL CALLED LORRY\A GIRL CALLED LORRY\DATABASE.MDF`
2. If doesn't work after the permissions, you can troubleshoot the SQL Localdb connections [using these steps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4609.troubleshoot-sql-server-2012-express-localdb.aspx)
3. Install SQL Express (as it's difficult to manage with LocalDB database engine), and attach `Database.mdf` into SQL Express engine. You can do this using following command via SSMS
4. Once your database ready at SQL Express, you can change your connection string to   `"Data Source=Localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourNewDBName;Integrated Security=True"`
5. In case issue even with SQL Express, [you may follow these steps..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758452/6598234)

```
--- You need to move "Database.mdf" and ".ldf" files into "C"\SQLData" folder before executing the command

CREATE DATABASE YourDatabase   
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\SQLData\Database.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'C:\SQLData\Database_log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Comment: Okay, so I was able to remove the changes added to my DB because my project is connected to a git repository. I simply pulled down the old DB from my repo so I could revert the changes back to what they originally were. I've checked my permissions for the .mdf file and I have all of the available permissions ticked when I go into properties for my DataBase.mdf and then I go into security I see that I have read write permissions as well as full control. I'm going to download SQL Express and give that a shot. Thank you very much. I appreciate your answer as this is a big project for me. :)

Comment: I tried opening my database in SMSS but I can't navigate to my database: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12xU1JkXLQ7Le-QvVFUOj6DUuYi7EOIM2/view?usp=sharing you can see in the image that the folder "me" is blank when I try to open it, is there any other way to access the file?

Comment: @googlewizard, as per your screenshot if the file extension `.mdf` it must be show-up there. Does it show any files when you change  `Database Data files (.mf)` to `All files (.*)` in drop down selection. As alternative, you can use `T-SQL` script (mentioned in answer) to attach your `.mdf` file

Comment: No, I can't access the folder containing my DB since it shows blank. Take a look at the image again: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12xU1JkXLQ7Le-QvVFUOj6DUuYi7EOIM2/view notice how there are no folders within "me" even though there actually is but I can't see them in this program. Changing to all files (.*) still shows nothing unfortunately.