# What does localsql mean in connection string?

Tags: sql-server, server

I am in the process of migrating sites from server A to server B, in the connection string, data source of some of the sites in server A, it says `localsql` but there is no ssms on server A because of which I am unable to find any databases on server A.

More interestingly, I have moved one site with `localsql` in the connection string to server B and the site is still working as expected.

I want to make sure there are no databases on server A and I want to know what exactly does `localsql` means in this context.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Adding connection string

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=localsql; Initial Catalog=dbname; User ID=id; Password=pw" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: SSMS is an application to interact with SQL Server, you don't need it to have a SQL Server instance running on the host. In Fact, SQL Server and SSMS have been separate installations since SQL server 2014.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I know, what I am looking for here is a way with which I can see if there are any databases on server A since I cannot check that with ssms.

Comment: That looks more like you're accessing a remote host, that is (oddly) called `localsql`.

Comment: @Larnu Yes thats what I am guessing, that localsql here is some other server. Weird, anyways thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the site hosted with [LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) (named instance) which is light version of SQL Engine runs without a service. Usually, this can be identified by looking at connection string (which directly pointing the `.mdf` file) as it's different than regular SQL Server connection strings.

If it's `localdb`, [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57770415/6598234) might be helpful to migrate the `.mdf` to SQL Server.

Comment: The connection string is not pointing to .mdf file, in fact I have the searched the server for any .mdf files and I could not find any.

Comment: Include the connection string in the question, @FakharAhmadRasul  (just hide any sensitive information)

Comment: @Larnu Connection string added.

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul, Thanks for the edit, it doesn't seem to be `localdb` connection string. probably it's connecting to another server (SERVER-C) when you mention the name `localsql` in connection string. You could do `ping localsql` identity that

Comment: @ShekarKola I tried pinging `localsql` but that didnt work. However I found the database, it on another server but I have no idea how `localsql` could mean another server. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul, it's bad naming convention of servers. i meant for `ping` is to recognize which IP the DNS resolving for the name `localsql`