# SQL Server Connection Error - Server Does Not Exist or Access Denied

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

We are trying to migrate an Access back-end to a new SQL Server database and are getting errors trying to connect to the database from client machines on the network.  I have reviewed numerous articles on the web and have been able to eliminate a lot of possible causes, but I am still stuck and would appreciate any insights.

Here is the background:

- Small company network with a primary domain & file server
- Could not successfully install SQL Server on that machine, so the IT guys created a new Hyper-V machine on that box and installed `SQLExpress` within that Hyper V
- While logged in to that Hyper V machine, everything appears to function correctly.
  SSMS runs and I can query all data
  o   I deployed a new Access Front End and CAN connect to the SQL database
  o   I can create ODBC connections to the database
  o   I have a DSN file which CAN be used to connect an Access froint end to the
  database

The problems start when I take the new Access Front end to a client machine on the network and try to create the connection to the new db – I get the

> Server Does Not Exist Or Access Denied Error Message.

I have tried numerous processes to connect but keep getting the same error.  To minimize variables, my testing now uses a copy of the same `DSN` file that which was successful on the Hyper V machine.

Here is the DSN contents:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=SQL Server
DATABASE=JobFileDat_SQL
WSID=WORKFILE
APP=Microsoft Office
Trusted_Connection=Yes
SERVER=WORKFILE\WORKFILE
Description=test via new data source
```

Here is what I have done so far:
o   Verified SQL Server
o   It is running
o   It DOES allow Remote Connections
o   Added new Inbound firewall rule to allow traffic over Port `1433` on the client machine
o   Verified that I CAN `ping` the Hyper V machine from the client machine
o   From the Hyper V machine, I have run SS Configuration Manager
o   I have enabled both Named Pipes and `TCP/IP`
o   I even tried creating a new firewall rule to support OUTBOUND traffic over   Port `1433`

Given that I can run/connect while on the HyperV machine, I am assuming that the issue is network related but that is certainly not an area of expertise for me.  So, I would welcome any further insights or suggestions.

Thanks very much,

David

Comment: Since this is not programming-related, I'm voting to migrate this to [dba.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's SQL Express, verify following:

1. Ensure the `SQL Browser` service is running within Hyper-v host where `SQL Express` is running.
2. Once `SQL Browser` service started, enable the port `1434` (TCP and UDP) at in-bond firewall rules
3. Do `telnet <hostname/ip> 1433` if all well, telnet must be succeeded. otherwise, you may follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758452/6598234) for further troubleshooting
4. If telnet works, seems you been using trusted connection, make sure the same (windows) user got access at SQL Express server

Comment: Thanks Shekar.  I am away from the machine for a while but I will try these as soon as I can.  I really appreciate the response.

Comment: I followed Shekar's advice and I added FOUR Inbound Rules:
1) Port 1433 TCP and UDP
2) Port 1434 TCP and UDP.

I am not sure if all four were required, but that seemed to do the trick.  I was then able to try TELNET, and I was also able to connect to the SQL database on the Server.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you link the tables using a FILE dsn. Access converts FILE dsn's automatic to DSN-less for you. After you link the tables, then the DSN is ignored and not used (nor is it required). So, if you used a FILE dsn, then changing the DSN will NOT update the linked tables until such time you re-link anyway. (this could be your issue).

What this suggests is that you have to re-link on the client computer (if you don't have some VBA code at startup to re-link). Once you do this manual re-link, then you should be able to distribute the compiled accDE front end to each workstation, and do so without having to setup a DSN on each workstation, and in fact you as a general rule don't even have to re-link the tables. So, I would go with a FILE dsn, as this gets around having to use the registry (a system/user DSN both use the registry - and you oh so often these days require elevated rights to edit/modify the registry settings anyway). So using a FILE DSN avoids these security issues. Note that you can't pre-link the tables until such time you can actually connect. I would thus dispense with using system/user DSN's, since security issues will get in your way.